# Why synchronization in Java preserves visibility of states being updated by multiple threads

Tags: java

I understand that synchronization can be used to enforce variable visibility being updated by more than one thread. i.e. Suppose we have an variable shared by two threads. If we update it in one thread, the other one is not guaranteed to see the newly updated value unless we properly synchronize the access to this variable.

But I want to know what happened under the cover to cause this. Can someone let me know?

Many thanks.

Comment: java uses lock on the objects and methods on which the method is being called so that while one therad is updating an object other thread can not update the same object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many other way to ensure visibility such as volatile, ordered/lazy set.

When you enter a synchronized block it performs a read barrier.  This means all reads after it will be consistent.  When you exit a synchronized block it performs a write barrier.  This ensures that all writes are in a consistent order.  The actual details of how this is done is determined by the CPU, but for x86/x64 it is a single machine code instruction or prefix.

Comment: However, IIRC, the happens-before is *only* guaranteed with the same monitor.

Comment: @user2864740 on x86/x64 there is no way to say keep these fields in correct order, but not those.  The barrier is for all reads or writes and I suspect it is for all implementations of Java.  Java 8 will add explicit methods for a read and write barrier.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs on multi-processor CPU's. If the variable is not volatile, the JIT compiler will optimize its use to be kept in cache or in the registers of each cpu core separately. Threads running simultaneously on other cores will not see changes to the variable until it's saved to RAM or the cache is flushed.

If you write to a volatile variable or another synchronisation, all CPU caches are flushed immediately.